# batch file to encrypt password and login in the normal password

Tags: passwords

I make a batch file when I create a password so it will save it in the file `accounts.uf`. I want to be able to change the extension to `txt` and have the password appear in `accounts.txt`, but I want to encrypt it.

Here is an example:

When I set my password to `1`, it should write in password file `6k5j4kjfdkj` (encrypted). When I login to in my program it needs the password to continue, but I need to write the cleartext password not the encrypted password.

(Please write the encrypted password code alone and use the normal password in login code alone.)

Comment: Why not store your passwords in something like [Keypass](http://keepass.info/)

Comment: I agree with @50-3 Neither batch nor text files were meant for encrypting passwords

Comment: @AthomSfere Yer I've submitted it as as answer with a full explanation, I think it's just a case of user inexperience so hopefully OP will learn from  this :)

Answer (score 2):

## Not full answer

*Suggesting alternative method not solution*

---

Batch files and text files are not an ideal solution for storing password.

You can encrypt the drive that these files reside on to make them "Secure" but I wouldn't call that ideal

Your best solution would be to use a 3rd party software package to store you passwords in an encrypted DB

**Example [Keypass](http://keepass.info/)**

> KeePass is a free open source password manager, which helps you to manage your passwords in a secure way. You can put all your passwords in one database, which is locked with one master key or a key file. So you only have to remember one single master password or select the key file to unlock the whole database. The databases are encrypted using the best and most secure encryption algorithms currently known (AES and Twofish).

[image: Keypass]

I personally use this for work as I have ~200 diffrent passwords to remember

---

There are plenty of solutions like this so do some research but what your looking at doing is far far far away from an ideal solution

Comment: i think you not understand >> i have program to lock and unlock folders but it don`t have password then i made a batch file to start it if you know the password and the password is not encrypt (any budy can change the extension to text and know the password) put i want  to encrypt the password can any one give encrypt code ?

Comment: can any one help my ??

Comment: You've asked a question that is very bad practice in application and You're unlikely to get a better response then what has been given. Your best bet if it needs to be a batch is to find a solution similar to Keypass that can pass stored information through command line arguments